# Overfull \hbox warnings for the glossary option "style=long" when using KOMA-Script?

Tags: koma-script, glossaries

I always get an overfull `\hbox` warning when I compile a glossary with the `glossaries` package and the option `style=long`. Also the warning occurs only with KOMA-Script classes and not with the standard classes.
Normally I'm using `lualatex`, but `pdflatex` produces the same warnings.
When I have more than 10 acronyms I get a similar second overfull `\hbox` warning.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? Or do I just have to live with it?

Here a MWE which produces the warnings:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
%\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,style=long]{glossaries}

 \makeglossaries

\newacronym{a}{a}{a}
\newacronym{b}{b}{b}
\newacronym{c}{c}{c}
\newacronym{d}{d}{d}
\newacronym{e}{e}{e}
\newacronym{f}{f}{f}
\newacronym{g}{g}{g}
\newacronym{h}{h}{h}
\newacronym{i}{i}{i}
\newacronym{j}{j}{j}
\newacronym{k}{k}{k}
%\newacronym{l}{l}{l}
%\newacronym{m}{m}{m}
%\newacronym{n}{n}{n}
%\newacronym{o}{o}{o}
%\newacronym{p}{p}{p}

\begin{document}
\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [bug report](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&category=glossaries&status=All&search_string=&key=92) for package `glossaries`. The package `glossaries` uses `\hsize` before `\begin{document}` while the official setup is done after calculation of \columnwidth in \begin{document}. Note that the MWE in the bug report is using the standard class `article`.

Workaround for `style=long`:

```
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,style=long]{glossaries}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{.6\columnwidth}%
  \setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{.1\columnwidth}%
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,style=long]{glossaries}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{.6\columnwidth}%
  \setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{.1\columnwidth}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{a}{a}{a}
\newacronym{b}{b}{b}
\newacronym{c}{c}{c}
\newacronym{d}{d}{d}
\newacronym{e}{e}{e}
\newacronym{f}{f}{f}
\newacronym{g}{g}{g}
\newacronym{h}{h}{h}
\newacronym{i}{i}{i}
\newacronym{j}{j}{j}
\newacronym{k}{k}{k}
\newacronym{l}{l}{l}
\newacronym{m}{m}{m}
\newacronym{n}{n}{n}
\newacronym{o}{o}{o}
\newacronym{p}{p}{p}

\begin{document}
\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,]
\end{document}
```

**Update** The bug is fixed in `glossaries-extra`. This new package is an extension of `glossaries`. So you can use

```
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,style=long]{glossaries-extra}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nicola Talbot implemented this fix in the package [glossaries-extra](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra)

```
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,style=long]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
```