# Glossaries in a scrbook with three columns

Tags: longtable, glossaries, columns, scrbook

I want to print a normal glossary with three columns: The name, the description and the page list. It works fine if the documentclass is a book. It doesn't matter if I'm using external programs like makeindex or not, but for the purpose of simplification I'm using `\makenoidxglossaries`. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{name={lorem},description={ipsum}}
\newglossaryentry{dolor}{name={dolor},description={sit}}
\newglossaryentry{amet}{name={amet},description={consectetuer}}
\newglossaryentry{adipiscing}{name={adipiscing},description={elit}}
\newglossaryentry{ut}{name={ut},description={purus}}
\newglossaryentry{elit}{name={elit},description={vestibulum}}
\newglossaryentry{placerat}{name={placerat},description={ac}}
\newglossaryentry{vitae}{name={vitae},description={felis}}

\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Glossary with book document class]

But, when im using scrbook:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{name={lorem},description={ipsum}}
\newglossaryentry{dolor}{name={dolor},description={sit}}
\newglossaryentry{amet}{name={amet},description={consectetuer}}
\newglossaryentry{adipiscing}{name={adipiscing},description={elit}}
\newglossaryentry{ut}{name={ut},description={purus}}
\newglossaryentry{elit}{name={elit},description={vestibulum}}
\newglossaryentry{placerat}{name={placerat},description={ac}}
\newglossaryentry{vitae}{name={vitae},description={felis}}

\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

I have following output and also the warning:

> Overfull \hbox (5399.75533pt too wide) in alignment at lines 19--19

[image: Glossary with scrbook document class]

The middle column is much too wide, so I don't see the page list anymore.

Comment: I expect you need to set the length `\glsdescwidth` (for example, `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{.5\textwidth}`). If you temporarily switch to `long3colborder` you'll see the extent of each column. I suspect the width of the second column is too wide causing the third column to disappear off the edge of the page.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with version KOMA-Script versions 3.17 - 3.19a, but not with the current 3.20 or 3.21. It seems to be a result of the "To early usage of `\hsize`" problem (see http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&category=glossaries&status=All&search_string=&key=92 ). Maybe you can use the new `glossaries-extra` instead `glossaries`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to this [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282316/overfull-hbox-warnings-for-the-glossary-option-style-long-when-using-koma-scr), where they link to a [bug report](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&category=glossaries&status=All&search_string=&key=92). The suggested workaround is to add `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}`. The complete code is then:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{name={lorem},description={ipsum}}
\newglossaryentry{dolor}{name={dolor},description={sit}}
\newglossaryentry{amet}{name={amet},description={consectetuer}}
\newglossaryentry{adipiscing}{name={adipiscing},description={elit}}
\newglossaryentry{ut}{name={ut},description={purus}}
\newglossaryentry{elit}{name={elit},description={vestibulum}}
\newglossaryentry{placerat}{name={placerat},description={ac}}
\newglossaryentry{vitae}{name={vitae},description={felis}}

\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```